# How to get a Pytorch data loader per class?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I want to train my model on 1 MNIST class at a time.

I can load the data with a general loader:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torchvision.datasets as datasets
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.autograd import Variable


trans = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (1.0,))])
# if not exist, download mnist dataset
root = './data'
train_set = datasets.MNIST(root=root, train=True, transform=trans, download=True)

batch_size = 100

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
                 dataset=train_set,
                 batch_size=batch_size,
                 shuffle=True)
```

But I'm not sure how to create 10 loaders (1 for each of the classes/digits) from this general loader (or just 10 loaders initially)

Comment: is there a reason why you don't want to start by creating 10 different loaders rather than breaking a single loader up?

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos not at all, I just didn't know it's possible. I'm going to edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rather simple solution would involve grouping the dataset by truth value, and creating a unique dataloader per group:

```py
...
from torch.utils.data import Subset, DataLoader

subsets = {target: Subset(train_set, [i for i, (x, y) in enumerate(train_set) if y == target]) for _, target in train_set.class_to_idx.items()}
loaders = {target: DataLoader(subset) for target, subset in subsets.items()}
```

you can then pick out a specific loader based on class index:

```py
class_3_loader = loaders[3]
```

Comment: Neat! Then if I want to train on digit 3/class 3 how do I specify which loader?

Comment: edited the answer

Comment: Just to verify, I need to replace `dataset` with `train_set`, and `DataLoader` with `train_loader`? Wondering because you did have `train_set` before but then you had `dataset` that was undefined and `DataLoader` is also undefined

Comment: `train_set` you define, `DataLoader` you need to import

Comment: I'm getting `NameError: name 'target' is not defined` in `----> 1 loaders = {target: DataLoader(subset) for subset in subsets}`

Comment: edited again --

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot! Sorry for all the trouble : )

Comment: no worries, I lost track of things along the edits :)